# Error matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data

```
city    inc pop edu crime   cult
New-York    29343,00    8683,00 0,00    10,40   0,00
Moscow  25896,00    17496,00    0,00    10,20   1,0
Rome    21785,00    15063,00    0,00    14,20   1,00
London  20000,00    70453,00    1,00    18,00   1,00
Berlin  44057,00    57398,00    1,00    6,30    1,00
```

I try to build plot and give name to `plot` and change color to columns

```
desire_salary = (df[(df['inc'] >= int(salary_people))])
fig = plt.figure()
result = desire_salary.pivot_table('city', 'cult', aggfunc='count').plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.75, rot=0, label="Presence / Absence of cultural centre")
plt.xlabel("Cultural centre")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.set_title('Salary and culture')
plt.plot(result[[0]], color='red')
plt.plot(result[[1]], color='blue')
plt.show()
```

But it returns error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_title'` and `TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Write `plt.title("Some title")`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the `set_title` method from the `AxesSubplot` class, but you are not using the mpl object-oriented approach. There are two ways to correct this:

1. Use `plt.title('Salary and culture')`
2. Switch to the more flexible OO approach, and set the title and axes labels using the relevant `Axes` methods, such as `ax.set_title`, `ax.set_xlabel`, etc.

The source of your second error is that when you call `.plot` on the `pivot_table`, you return a matplotlib `AxesSubplot` object, not the `DataFrame`. So then you try to plot `result[[0]]`, it is trying to index an `AxesSubplot` object.

```
desire_salary = (df[(df['inc'] >= int(salary_people))])
fig = plt.figure()

# Create the pivot_table
result = desire_salary.pivot_table('city', 'cult', aggfunc='count')

# plot it in a separate step. this returns the matplotlib axes
ax = result.plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.75, rot=0, label="Presence / Absence of cultural centre", ax=ax)

ax.set_xlabel("Cultural centre")
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency")
ax.set_title('Salary and culture')

ax.plot(result[[0]], color='red')
ax.plot(result[[1]], color='blue')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I have no first error, but second `TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` didn't dissapear

Comment: Ah, I see your problem. When you call `plot` on the pivot_table, that returns the axes it is plotted on, not the pivot table. I'll edit the answer

Comment: It's strange. Color didn't change. It's blue to all columns

Answer (score 0):

to try "return_type = 'dict'" for TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.